# Disabling VisualStates in code behind - WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I disable VisualState animations on ListBox in code behind? I've created Selected and Unselected VisualState storyboard animation for ListBoxItem but when my ListBox ItemsSource changes ListBox Selected and Unselected animation is performed (I think all items get selected and unselected for a second automatically).

EDIT:
Found workaround solution - if you're getting Selected and Unselected animations on items source changing you can use it. Seems like this automated selection changes doesn't even raise SelectionChanged event.

```
public class ListBoxSelectedFoldersAnimationBehaviour : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += ListBoxOnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= ListBoxOnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void ListBoxOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        foreach (var item in selectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems)
        {
            var listBoxItem = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
            if (listBoxItem != null)
                SetItemSelectedAnimation(listBoxItem);
        }

        foreach (var item in selectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems)
        {
            var listBoxItem = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
            if (listBoxItem != null) // listboxitem can be null after removing item from ListBox.ItemsSource
                SetItemUnselectedAnimation(listBoxItem);
        }
    }

    private void SetItemSelectedAnimation(ListBoxItem item)
    { // sample opacity animation
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut },
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)),
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.6
        };
        storyboard.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, item);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(storyboard, new PropertyPath(ListBoxItem.OpacityProperty));
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    private void SetItemUnselectedAnimation(ListBoxItem item)
    { // sample opacity animation
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn },
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)),
            From = 0.6,
            To = 1.0
        };
        storyboard.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, item);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(storyboard, new PropertyPath(ListBoxItem.OpacityProperty));
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
}


xaml:
<Page xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
      xmlns:classNamespace="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.NamespaceOfBehaviourClass">
...

<ListBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <classNamespace:ListBoxSelectedFoldersAnimationBehaviour/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

I haven't checked does it leaks memory yet (cause i'm not stopping storyboards) so keep that in mind.

Comment: Have you tried setting the StoryBoard of the VisualState to null, and restoring it after populating the ListBox?

var sb = Selected.Storyboard;
Selected.Storyboard = null;
...            
Selected.Storyboard = sb;

Comment: Did you try to edit ListBox control template? Copy whole control template of ListBox and comment lines of the visual states that you want to disable.